# Synchronization primitive "lock once"

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I need a synchronization primitive which is similar to Monitor but doesn't require to Exit it as many times as I have enter it. If I enter Monitor by one thread and then reenter it by the same thread I will need to call Monitor.Exit twice. But I need to exit it by one call.

Now I use a some kind of Monitor wrapper which doesn't enter Monitor if it was already entered by current thread (and that's why then I can exit it by one call). But may be .NET Framework contains one?

Comment: Not an answer, but: reentrant locks are not a good idea... http://zaval.org/resources/library/butenhof1.html

Comment: Microsoft lets you configure ReaderWriterLockSlim (for example) to be entered recursively, but they don't think it's a good idea either. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious to know why you would ever call `Monitor.Enter` multiple times without an equal number of calls to `Monitor.Exit`. Typically any such synchronization code would look like this:

```
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
    // some code that needs to be synchronized
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
}
```

Assuming you are using `try`/`finally` wherever you acquire a lock using `Monitor.Enter` (which you *should* be), I'm having trouble seeing why you would need this "lock-once" class you're asking about.

In fact, you should basically never have to do this yourself anyway, as a much simpler approach that does essentially the same thing is to use a `lock` statement:

```
lock (lockObject)
{
    // some code that needs to be synchronized
}
```

That said, I could certainly just be missing something.

Comment: That could be the case with recursive functions, when you need to lock on the first entry only.

Answer (score 0):

how do you know it's the same thread and how to you ensure that when this threads leaves it is going to call exit before it leaves?

From the looks of it, you just need something else (in an outer level) that has the lock. Maybe an "entry point" method that locks and calls another method that has the meat of the work then you can call this other method many times without going past the lock.

```
public static void MethodOne()
{
  lock (lockObj)
  {
    MethodTwo();
  }
}

private static void MethodTwo()
{
  //This method can be called multiple times
  //without going past MethodOne and so you only
  //lock once
}

private static void MethodThree()
{
}
```